# async update(params, data, { files } = {}) does not work

Tags: strapi

my project was created with Strapi 3.0.0-beta.18.6.
But in the service of the content type "Orders" the (new) "update" method does not work, only the (old) "edit" works.
Can someone give me a tip?

```
  // ---------------- "update" does not work :( ------------------ 
  async update(params, data, { files } = {}) {
    const query = strapi.query('order');
    const entry = await query.update(params, data);

    if (files) {
      // automatically uploads the files based on the entry and the model
      await this.uploadFiles(entry, files, { model: strapi.models.order });
      return this.findOne({ id: entry.id });
    }

    return entry;
  },
```

by the way, `query.update(params, data);` cannot be executed, the process is canceled, but there is no error message.

```
  // ---------------- old "edit" works ------------------ 

  async edit (params, values) {
    // Extract values related to relational data.
    const relations = _.pick(values, Order.associations.map(ast => ast.alias));
    const data = _.omit(values, Order.associations.map(ast => ast.alias));

    // Create entry with no-relational data.
    const entry = Order.forge(params).save(data);

    // Create relational data and return the entry.
    return Order.updateRelations(Object.assign(params, { values: relations }));
  },
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by the way, `query.update(params, data);` cannot be executed, the process is canceled, but there is no error message.

Answer (score 0):

Strapi generated controllers are based on the shadow `core` controller function.

If you want to customize the default function you can refer to this documentation : https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#core-controllers

I just tried it and it works fine.